# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error in my code

Tags: java

Cant find the error in coins array. when i tried to initialize the array with n+10 elements it worked. but  actually it should be using only the n elements. where am i getting it wrong?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MaximumContiguousSum {

        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int amount, n; 
            System.out.print("Enter number of types of coins : ");
            n = in.nextInt();
            int[] coins = new int[n];
            System.out.print("Enter coins values : ");
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                coins[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the amount : ");
            amount = in.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[amount+1];
            arr[1]=1; arr[0]=0;
            for(int i=2; i<=amount; i++){
                arr[i]=100;
                int j=0;

//Error in the following line
                while(coins[j]<=i && j<n){
                    arr[i]=min(arr[i], 1+arr[i-coins[j]]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The number of coins to be used : " + arr[amount]);
            in.close();
        }

        private static int min(int a, int b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (a<b)?a:b;
        }
    }


Output:

    Enter number of types of coins : 3
    Enter coins values : 1 2 7
    Enter the amount : 10
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at MaximumContiguousSum.main(MaximumContiguousSum.java:22)
```

Comment: Which line is line 22? as shown by: `MaximumContiguousSum.java:22`

Comment: while(coins[j]<=i && j<=n){

Comment: If `j` is equal to `n`, the index is out of bounds for the array `coins`. Put `j < n` before `coins[j] <= i`, and the loop will stop before this problem happens.

Comment: What's your program intended to do? What's the expected output?

Comment: it is a dp problem "Making Change"
Output should be 3.
I have tried with "while(coins[j]<=i && j<n){" too.. Still array out of bound

Comment: actually there should be no error.. why is there an error

Comment: Funny, I see a question mark and I see, below, actual answers, so apparently this isn't such an egregious post. Just a newbie looking for help. Don't want to help? Find another post. I see way too much snarky stuff like this. Not sure of the point. In fact, given the nature of the error, I think this is a pretty good question. It does NOT go without saying that NO EFFORT was put into this. Plus 1, @EJP, to offset your -1.

Comment: I got it.. it should be while(j<n && coins[j]<=i)... it should check j<n condition before coins[j]<i condition

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int[] coins = new int[n];
```

declares coins to have n elements with maximum index n - 1

this

```
while(coins[j]<=i && j<=n){
   arr[i]=min(arr[i], 1+arr[i-coins[j]]);
```

Will attempt to access coins[n] when j = n which is past the end

Edit: arr[i-coins[j]] is protected against.

finally this:

```
while(coins[j]<=i && j<n)
```

should be this

```
while(j < n && coins[j]<=i)
```

Comment: doesnt wrk with j<n too

Comment: it wont check with j=2 and i=2 bcoz theres condition coins[j]<=i since 7<2 wont go in the loop

Comment: Yea, you're right about that one.  I'll leave it in for context, though

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error. Your line:

```
while(coins[j]<=i && j<=n)
```

Will try to grab coins[n] before it quits, and the final index of your array is actually n-1

Comment: But it also works when j==n, so when you use it in coins[j], you end up with the array out of bound error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check greater than or equal on the error line

change this `while(coins[j]<=i && j<n){` to `while(coins[j]<i && j<n){` in your code